# react-fullpage - avoid setState infinite loop in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullpage.js

TLDR Question: Basically i want to hide sidenav button when the footer is open.

In my `App.js` i am rendering the navigation and react-fullpage (scroll to section component) and passing the isFooterOpen state and methods that change it.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { isFooterOpen: false };
  show = () => { this.setState({ isFooterOpen: true }); };
  hide = () => { this.setState({ isFooterOpen: false }); };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navigation
          isFooterOpen={this.state.isFooterOpen}
          hide={this.hide}
          show={this.show}
        />

        <FullPageWrapper
           isFooterOpen={this.state.isFooterOpen}
           hide={this.hide}
           show={this.show}
           {...fullpageOptions}
        />              
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Navigation passes down the state to the sideButton where i show/hide it based on it, which works fine.

Problem is when i want to trigger that state change from my FullpageWrapper where i am detecting whether i am scrolling past last section or scrolling up from the last section.

Component is using render props so basically i am calling setState there in render and it causes infinite loop which i get but i can't find a workaround to access that state (direction, index and so on). Even toggleFooter function feels a bit "hacky" because i am setting properties to that state object instead of somehow keeping my own state with that npm ReactFullpage component.

**FullpageWrapper.js**

```
function toggleFooter(state, props) {
  if (state.callback === "onLeave") {
    if (state.direction === "down") {
      const emptySection = document.querySelector("#empty");
      if (emptySection.classList.contains("active")) {
        state.isFooterOpen = true;
        // props.show(); // change app state and hide side button - infinite loop here
      }
    } else if (state.direction === "up" && state.origin.index === 5) {
      state.isFooterOpen = false;
      // props.hide(); // change app state and hide side button - infinite loop here
    }
  }
}

const FullPageWrapper = fullpageProps => (
  <ReactFullpage
    {...fullpageProps}
    render={({ state, fullpageApi }) => {
      toggleFooter(state, fullpageProps);

      return (
        <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
          <HeroSection />
          <AboutSection />
          <TeamSection />
          <ServicesSection />
          <ContactSection />
          <Empty />    
          <Footer isFooterOpen={state.isFooterOpen} />
        </div>
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

I tried also simple event Bus where i dispatch an event from FullpageWrapper but i am still dispatching it from render so it's the same problem...

I stripped out everything unnecessary and here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/34rj681lv6) example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your `setState` calls with an `if` statement, I'd guess that that would remove the infinite loop?

I've created an updated code sandbox here, and it looks like it functions as you've designed:

https://codesandbox.io/s/p39w4z51pq

`show = () => { 
  if(!this.state.isFooterOpen) { 
    this.setState({ isFooterOpen: true }); 
  }
};
hide = () => { 
  if(this.state.isFooterOpen) { 
    this.setState({ isFooterOpen: false });
  } 
};`

Comment: This works man, was trying now with some global variable (was a bit desperate) but thank you so much! It makes sense after all.

Comment: Great! I can imagine that each one of these calls would retrigger render props and round it would go in a loop. I'll have to read a little more to understand the flow here!